# iframe is not found via xpath even iframe is exists

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver, xpath, iframe

Given the xpath `//iframe[@id='gst_main']`

My DOM Element is `<iframe title="Main Content" id="gst_main" name="gst_main" src="incident_list.do?sysparm_query= slot="apple-ui" style="visibility: visible;"></iframe>`

The problem is the xpath is not found in DOM by using chrome dev tools

Comment: Check if a namespace is in use.

Comment: where do i check this namespace and how can i use it

Comment: This question is missing a minimal debugging details

Comment: @sekhar Does your input document (besides the snippet you showed to us) contain attributes like `xmlns`? If yes, you are using namespaces and want to check https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+xpath+namespace